# Help identifying SMD MOSFET for electronic speed control (ESC) - top markings DB08AC 8010

Tags: mosfet, identification, motor-controller

[image: photo of components on PCB]

I am repairing a few MOSFETs on an ESC. The markings says DB08AC and 8010. The 8010 looks like maybe an OnSemi chip, but I am not sure as the logo does not seem correct. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a cheap copy of ON Semiconductor’s **FDMC8010** NMOS.
[Datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fdmc8010-d.pdf)

[image]

I have seen variations of this FET used in a few ESCs with up to 30 A current rating. Here are two examples that I remember [Aikon 30A ESC](https://www.aikon-electronics.com/index.php?id=6), [Blitz Mini 4in1 ESC](https://anubisrc.com/product/blitz-mini-2-6s-e55-4-in-1-blheli32-esc/)

[image]

**Aikon 30A 4in1 showing the FETs**

[image]

**Blitz Mini 2-6S showing the FETs**

I hope this helps!